# Running and filtering reports in Apex

Tags: unit-test, reporting, bug

I just spun up a brand new Dev Org (00DHp000002yxab), and copy-pasted code from this Salesforce support article:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_analytics_test_reports.htm into a unit test.

```
@isTest
public class ReportsInApexTest {
    @isTest(SeeAllData='true')
    public static void testSyncReportWithTestData() {
    
      // Create an Opportunity Object.
      Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name='ApexTestOpp', StageName='stage',
          Probability = 95, CloseDate=system.today());
      insert opp;
      
      List <Report> reportList = [SELECT Id,DeveloperName FROM Report where
          DeveloperName = 'New_Opportunities_Report_Scy'];
      String reportId = (String)reportList.get(0).get('Id');
      
      Reports.ReportMetadata reportMetadata =
          Reports.ReportManager.describeReport(reportId).getReportMetadata();
      
      // Add a filter.
      List<Reports.ReportFilter> filters = new List<Reports.ReportFilter>(); 
      Reports.ReportFilter newFilter = new Reports.ReportFilter();
      newFilter.setColumn('OPPORTUNITY_NAME');
      newFilter.setOperator('equals');
      newFilter.setValue('ApexTestOpp');
      filters.add(newFilter);
      reportMetadata.setReportFilters(filters);
      
      Reports.ReportResults result =
          Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId,reportMetadata,false);
      Reports.ReportFact grandTotal = (Reports.ReportFact)result.getFactMap().get('T!T');
      System.assertEquals(1,(Decimal)grandTotal.getAggregates().get(0).getValue());
    }
}
```

I created an Opportunity report and set the filters to this

[image]

The assertion on line 30 fails.

I tried using System.runAs to make sure that the report is run by the same User that creates the Opportunity.  It didn't work.

I tried wrapping things in Test.StartTest and Test.StopTest (even though it shouldn't matter because this is a synchronous report run).  It didn't work.

If I manually create an Opportunity in the Org with a Name of 'ApexTestOpp' then the assertion succeeds.  The report running in the unit test is not seeing the records created by the unit test.

I tried to report this through Salesforce Support and they said my company would need to upgrade to Premium Support in order for them to even take a look at it, which is completely absurd.  This is broken.  Salesforce needs to fix it.  I'm posting here in the hope that someone from Salesforce sees it and can do something about it.

Comment: for Charles and other people answering - we were able to confirm that this is a timing issue. Whether it's a bug or working as designed is unclear but likely the latter. An answer with more details will be posted at some later point.

Answer (score 0):

I diffed the example code from the developer.salesforce page against your code and I found just one difference. In your assert statement you're getting the first item in the List `get(0)`, but the example code is getting the second item `get(1)`.

I'm looking at the documentation trying to understand ReportFacts, getFactMap(), and getAggregates(), and I still feel confused, but posting here in case the List indexing is the issue.

Comment: Hey Jerry, thanks for taking a look.  The diff is because the report referenced in the documentation (Closed_Sales_This_Quarter) doesn't exist in a fresh dev org.  Based on get(1), I'm assuming it's a Summary report with at least one level of aggregation.  The report I created in my dev org is just a flat tabular report, so if you call get(1) against the results it throw a list index out of bounds exception.

But all of that shouldn't make a difference because if I manually create an actual Opportunity record in the org, everything works with my code and my report.